# Getting width of 2d object in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the new 2d tools in Unity3d, and I have a game object with a 2d polygonal collider attached to it. I just want to understand how to get the width of this object! Why is this so difficult? The collider nor the game object have anything that has a "bounds" or "size" property. 
Even if they did, however, how would I extrapolate width from a vector3 object? From what I understand about vector3 objects, they give a length (magnitude) from the origin of the scene. So how could I use distance from the scene's origin to determine with width of my game object? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/211486-Physics2D-Bounds-and-Extents?p=1424555&viewfull=1#post1424555), looks like 2D colliders indeed should have the missing bounds variable, and it will be made available in a future release.

So looks like for now you'll have to make do with a workaround. One could be to add a Sprite Renderer component to your GameObject, add a dummy image to it and set it disabled so it's never visible. Then you can use `gameObject.renderer.bounds` to get the sprite bounds.

Comment: Adding a sprite to the game object, and then getting the renderer.bounds.size.x of the game object worked!  Thanks!  Also, great link to that discussion.

Answer (score 15):

There are two ways(at least) to get this.

- The 1st is to user [Renderer.bounds](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html);
- The 2nd is to use [Collider.bounds](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider-bounds.html)

---

```
var renderer = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
int width = renderer.bounds.size.x;
```

---

or

---

```
var collider2D= gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
var collider = collider2D.collider; //Edit, thanks to Arttu's comment!
int width = collider.bounds.size.x;
```

---

For your 2D case, the former might be more appropriate.

Comment: [Collider2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html) was specified in the question, not Collider.

Comment: @ArttuPeltonen, thanks for the good comments, code updated! Thanks.

Comment: This is a great answer and I wish i could mark both answers correct.  However, the first one doesn't work unless i first add a sprite renderer to the component.  The second option doesn't work because the "collider" property of the collider2d, is null, but I don't know why.  However, you're the the first person i've seen explain that bounds.size.x means width, not "the x position" of the object's anchor point.

Comment: It's null because the gameObject doesn't have a `Collider` component (that is, a 3D collider), only `Collider2D`.

Comment: Collider2D.collider has been deprecated alongside with its 3D correspondent. :(