# Finding size of images imported at runtime

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, runtime, unityscript, dimensions

I am currently loading images at runtime from directories stored in an XML file, and assigning them to RawImage components via the WWW class. While this is working fine, the image is skewed to fit into the new texture size.

I am wondering how to get an image’s original size or aspect ratio so that I can change the size of the image rect to suit. The images to be imported are at varying sizes and therefore the approach used needs to be responsive to the original size of imported images.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. [Scripting in uJS]

Many thanks in advance, Ryan

```
function loadContextImage(texLocation : String)
{
    if (!imageView.activeSelf)
    {
        imageView.SetActive(true);
    }

    var wwwDirectory = "file://" + texLocation; //this will probably need to change for other OS (PC = file:/ [I think?]) - **REVISE**  
    var newImgTex = new Texture2D(512, 512);

    while(true){

        var www : WWW = new WWW(wwwDirectory);

        yield www;

        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(newImgTex);

        if (www.isDone){
            break; //if done downloading image break loop
        }
    }

    var imageRender : UI.RawImage = imageView.GetComponent.<RawImage>();
    imageRender.texture = newImgTex;
}
```

Comment: Can you use the preserve aspect ratio toggle?

Comment: Do NOT use "unityscript", it is deprecated. Change to c#.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting width of 2d object in unity 3d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060614/getting-width-of-2d-object-in-unity-3d)

Comment: @fafase there doesn't seem to be method in the RawImage class for preserving aspect ratio; is there another method you are referring to?

Comment: @Joe Blow thanks for the tip; I'm pretty invested in using uJS at this stage but will definitely be using c# in future projects.

The duplicate link you have included seems to refer to the use of bounds to acquire dimension sizes. I don't think this suits my use case as the image is imported at runtime and I need to find dimensions of the image itself before assigning it to a renderer.texture, to ensure the texture is set to an appropriate size and avoid the aforementioned incorrect aspect ratio.

Comment: Do you have to use RawImage? You could use an Image instead. I understand it is using Sprite and is more consuming but maybe it is what you need here.

Comment: Yep, have used the Image component in a similar use case however the issue seems to remain where by creating a new texture to assign to it I have to know the size of the original image.

Comment: Hi Ryan, do not use unityscript.  There's nothing to be invested in.  It's very fortunate that c# is actually *far easier to use*.

Comment: no big deal but on the link if you go down there's an answer explaining `GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x` etc.  it will literally tell you how big it is on the screen.  you use preserveAspectRatio as Faf explains.  (Generally check out *the various aspect ratio options* - very useful.) TBC it will ***set the size ratio for you automatically***. then if (for some reason) you need to ***know*** the size ratio of the finished item on -screen, just use .renderer size or the Texture2D as faf explains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot use an Image (for nay valid reasons), you can get the width and height of the texture:

```
WWW www = new WWW(url);
yield return www;
Texture2D tex = www.texture; 
float aspectRatio = tex.height / tex.width;
rawImage.width = width;
rawImage.height = width * aspectRatio;
```

This should make the rect of the image of the appropriate ratio of the texture.

If you can use Image and preserveAspectRatio, you get it done by Unity. The result is not necessarily the same since it will keep the dimensions of the box and make the Sprite occupies as much space while keeping ratio.