# Video player coroutine issues

Tags: video, unity-game-engine, runtime, unityscript, coroutine

I have a coroutine downloading an .ogg file at runtime via the www class, this is currently really inconsistent.

The video is intended to display at its normal size ([320 x 240px](http://answers.unity3d.com/storage/temp/64280-screen-shot-2016-02-20-at-73230-pm.png)), and sometimes this works. However, frequently the video is displayed at [16 x 16px](http://answers.unity3d.com/storage/temp/64281-screen-shot-2016-02-20-at-75446-pm.png).

It seems to me that this is largely due to the video not being downloaded completely using the current coroutine. I have followed the docs (ScriptRef/www-movie) to the best of my ability but to no avail, if anyone has any suggestions as to why this may be occurring I would be very grateful.

NB: scripting in uJS.

Many thanks in advance,

Ryan

```
 function loadContextVideo(texLocation : String)
 {
     var wwwDirectory = "file://" + texLocation; 

     var vidTex = www.movie;    //method 01 [using local variables]
 //    vidTex = www.movie;    //method 02 [using public variables]

     while(!vidTex.isReadyToPlay){ //****PROBLEM COROUTINE*****
         yield www;
         if (www.isDone)
         {
             break;
         }
     }

     var texWidth = vidTex.width;
     var texHeight = vidTex.height;
     Debug.Log("texWidth: " + texWidth + " texHeight: " + texHeight);

     //check img sizes
     var mvMaxWidth = imgRect.rect.width;
     var mvMaxHeight = imgRect.rect.height;
     Debug.Log("mvMaxWidth: " + mvMaxWidth + " mvMaxHeight: " + mvMaxHeight);

     if (texHeight > mvMaxHeight)
     {
         var scaleHFactor = mvMaxHeight /texHeight;
         texHeight = texHeight * scaleHFactor;
         texWidth = texWidth * scaleHFactor;        
     }
     if (texWidth > mvMaxWidth)
     {
         var scaleWFactor = mvMaxWidth /texWidth;
         texHeight = texHeight * scaleWFactor;
         texWidth = texWidth * scaleWFactor;
     }
     Debug.Log("texWidth: " + texWidth + " texHeight: " + texHeight);
     imgRect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(texWidth, texHeight);

     //Video Tex assign
     var imgView : UI.RawImage = imageView.GetComponent.<RawImage>(); //method 01 [using local variables]
 //    var imgView = imageRender; //method 02 [using public variables]
     imgView.texture = vidTex;

     //Video Audio assign
     var vidAudio : AudioSource = imageView.GetComponent.<AudioSource>(); 
     vidAudio.clip = vidTex.audioClip;

     //curVideo = vidTex;
     vidTex.Play();
     vidAudio.Play();    
 }
```

Comment: "unityscript" is now deprecated and is being removed from Unity. it would be very hard to do something like this using u/s.  (fortunately c# is actually far easier)

Comment: Hi @Joe Blow, thanks for the advice; you provided me similar feedback in another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35333910/finding-size-of-images-imported-at-runtime), and while I recognise the need to change from uJS, the time constraints in my current project does not allow for me to pick up C#. 

Are you able to tell me where the logic in the current coroutine is lapsing? It seems to be very close, but not reliable.

Comment: Try removing the www.isDone check.

Comment: Hi @fafase, thanks for the response! Have tested your suggestion and the same issue seems to persist. Are you able to explain your logic? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @fafase's advice, the issue seems to be *"a frame gap between the downloading being ready and the video file being ready"*. The answer to resolving this is to check both whether the www.file is done downloading and whether the video file is ready to be played as in the code below:

```js
function loadContextVideo(texLocation : String)
{
 var wwwDirectory = "file://" + texLocation;
 var www : WWW = new WWW(wwwDirectory);
 
 vidTex = www.movie;
  
// while(!vidTex.isReadyToPlay){ //problem coroutine
//  yield www;
//  if (www.isDone)
//  {
//   break;
//  }
  while(!www.isDone && !vidTex.isReadyToPlay){ //answer coroutine
  yield www;
  if (www.isDone && vidTex.isReadyToPlay)
  {
   break;
  }
 }

 var texWidth = vidTex.width;
 var texHeight = vidTex.height;

//rest of the code continues...
```